# How to ensure I'm behind the proxy in twython?

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I'm using TOR proxy to connect to Twython. But I saw that when I use a false `ip:port` like `666.666.666.666:666666` it still connects. So, how I can ensure/assert that I'm connected behind the proxy while using twython ?

```
from twython import Twython

client_args = {
    'proxies': {
        'socks5': '666.666.666.666:666666', # My TOR is 127.0.0.1:9000

    },
    'timeout': 300,
}

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, 
                  OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, client_args=client_args)
```

I also tried listening port 9000 with `sudo tcpflow -i any -C -J port 9000` but it gets traffic when I'm not running twython too... so it's unconclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could create an IP checking method, as so:

```
import urllib
import re

def IpCheck(request):
    theIP = re.findall(r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}", request)
    ip = ''.join(theIP)
    return ip

url = 'http://checkip.dyndns.org'
realip = IpCheck(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
torip = IpCheck(#method that properly reads the website with tor like above) #I dont use twython
```

set up your proxy, and then check the ip again through the proxy you are using.

Then you could check if the Ip's are the same with either

```
if realip == torip:
    print('Tor Isn't Working!')
else:
    print('Tor Enabled')
```

or a function:

```
def TorCheck(realip, torip):
    if realip == torip:
        return('Whatever you want it to return')
    else:
        return('Tor Is Enabled!')
```

or make it all one function:

```
def IpCheck(request, torrequest):
    theIP = re.findall(r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}", request)
    torip = re.findall(r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}", torrequest)
    ip = ''.join(theIP)
    tip= ''.join(torip)
    if tip == ip:
        return('Whatever you want it to return')
    else:
        return('Tor Is Enabled!')# + 'Using Ip: ' + tip)
realip = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
torip = #Tor method that reads the website var url
#isTor = IpCheck(realip, torip)
#print IpCheck(realip, torip)
#or print isTor
```

Comment: Thanks, But this IS NOT the problem. My TOR instance works and I know my IP's. The question is, How I can check that Twython is behind my proxy If when I try with an imposible `ip:port` like `666.666.666.666:666666` it still works... :$ What guarantees that i'm behind a proxy and not using my own connection ?